# Bootstrap Carousel doesn't render a slideshow

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm using Yii with Bootstrap.  And trying to slideshow a set of images from images folder.  It's the code, I used to display slide show images.

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbCarousel', array(
    'items' => array(
        array(
            'image' => 'images\DSC02786_1.jpg',
            'label' => 'First Thumbnail label',
            'caption' => 'jubiliant mood '),
        array(
            'image' => 'images\siva.jpg',
            'label' => 'Second Thumbnail label',
            'caption' => 'Another caption'),
        array(
            'image' => 'images\siva1.jpg',
            'label' => 'Third Thumbnail label',
            'caption' => 'Yet Another'),
    ),
));
```

It displays the images, one next another and not in slide show. As a newbie I couldn't locate the mistake I do.

Comment: Have you any JS errors on your console?

Comment: It's probably not your problem, but those backslashes should be forward slashes on the web.

Comment: No errors.   Images are getting displayed without any problem, one next another.

Comment: But slideshow is not working.  Changing to forward slashes also not working.

Comment: Try adding some `alert` statements into the JS library on your dev machine. I wonder if it is not being executed. Can you publish a live demo on the web?

Comment: I'm working only on my development machine (windows, php, mysql, yii, bootstrap).  I'm checking (better, learning) PHP & Yii. I just put this code into my index.php file, to view the output.   
Could not upload to website immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and corrected.  The above coding requires files from booster - yii extension, but my files were wrongly accessing bootstrap files.   I deleted and re-copied, files from booster extension, it's working fine now.

Thanks for your help.